# Data is not changing in html

Tags: javascript

I want to create a clock using java script. For this i'm using classes.

```js
const htmlMarkup = (hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0) => {
  console.log('render html')
  return (
    `<div class="clock">
           <h2>clock: ${hours} ${minutes} ${seconds}</h2>
        </div>`
  )
};

class Clock {
  constructor() {
    this.time = new Date();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getSeconds()
    }, 1000)
  }

  renderHTML() {
    return htmlMarkup(this.hours, this.minutes, this.getSeconds())
  }
  getSeconds() {
    return this.seconds = this.time.getSeconds()
  }

}

const runClock = new Clock();
document.querySelector(".app").innerHTML = runClock.renderHTML();
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

Even if i set:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  this.getSeconds()
}, 1000)
```

...the seconds are not changing. So, why the seconds still the same after first render of the application and how to ssolve the issue?

Comment: in the `setInterval`you should call the `renderHTML` method (btw what are `this.minutes` and `this.hours` supposed to be since you have never set them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. Your timer just calls `getSeconds`. `getSeconds` doesn't do anything to update the HTML. For that, you need to repeat the `document.querySelector(".app").innerHTML = runClock.renderHTML();` part. (In fact, the `Clock#getSectonds` method doesn't do anything useful and you can just get rid of it.)
2. Your code does `this.time = new Date()` and then just uses `this.time` throughout. That `Date` object is unchanging, it doesn't continually update itself. You don't need `this.time` at all, just use `new Date()` in `renderHTML`.
3. Your code never sets the hours or minutes, so it just shows `0`s for those.

Here's an example that modifies the constructor so it accepts the element to update, and then calls `renderHTML` in the timer callback, using `new Date` in `renderHTML` to get the current date/time. (I've also added various missing semicolons. You should either use them, nor not use them and rely on ASI instead, but not use them sporatically.)

```js
const htmlMarkup = (hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0) => {
    console.log('render html');
    return (
        `<div class="clock">
           <h2>clock: ${hours} ${minutes} ${seconds}</h2>
        </div>`
    );
};

class Clock {
    constructor(element) { 
        this.element = element;
        setInterval(()=> {
           this.element.innerHTML = this.renderHTML();
        },1000);
    }

    renderHTML() {
        const dt = new Date();
        return htmlMarkup(dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds());
    }

}

const runClock = new Clock(document.querySelector(".app"));
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ur not calling the `new Date()` again. check this.

```js
const htmlMarkup = (hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0) => {
  console.log("render html");
  return `<div class="clock">
         <h2>clock: ${hours} ${minutes} ${seconds}</h2>
      </div>`;
};

class Clock {
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getSeconds();
    }, 1000);
  }

  renderHTML() {
    return htmlMarkup(this.hours, this.minutes, this.getSeconds());
  }
  getSeconds() {
    this.time = new Date();
    this.seconds = this.time.getSeconds();
    console.log(this.time);
  }
}

const runClock = new Clock();
document.querySelector(".app").innerHTML = runClock.renderHTML();
```

Comment: when i try to output in html the seconds, there is not working. Could you show please?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following changes:

```
setInterval(()=> {
  document.querySelector(".app").innerHTML = runClock.renderHTML();
},1000)
```

And

```
getSeconds() {
          return (new Date()).getSeconds()
    }
```

Now only the seconds are changing. You'll have to handle for minutes and hours.